# Manipulating a HTML file input to dynamically add a link to the selected file WITHOUT uploading the file?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am not sure if what I am asking is actually possible but let me try to explain. I am trying to allow users to link to a local file, from an internal web application. Instead of having to hard code every link, I was wondering if it was possible to manipulate a HTML file input so that the user could browse to the file they wanted to link to. I do not wish for the files to actually be uploaded anywhere since they are already on a local drive, it seems silly to duplicate them, and down the line this would lead to multiple duplications (the PDF's are per product, and the same product will be referenced on multiple occasions).

I am aware after some research that due to security reasons you are not able to obtain the file path of a selected file unless perhaps by the use of a temporary URL. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav). Unfortunately this seems to be a very temperamental solution and I can't seem to wrap my head around how it works.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do what you want with out a browser extension.

Comment: Maybe use `window.URL.createObjectURL` as the href of a link?